# How to delete an element from an array based off the user input in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this. I have an array and the user is prompted with a question about what number should be deleted from the array. The number is stored and the result is a new array that gets outputted with the deleted value.

```
def delete(number)
  a = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
  puts "Please type number to be deleted?"
  number = gets
  result= a.delete(number)
  puts result
end
a.delete(number)
```

Comment: Do you want to delete just one element from the array? Also, what is your expected output?

Comment: The goal was to delete any element like 1 that appeared in the array. The output would be the array without the deleted elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe do something like this ?

```
  def delete(num,array)
    array.reject { |el| el == num }
    puts array
  end
  a = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
  puts "Please type number to be deleted? from array #{a}"
  number = gets
  delete(number.to_i,a)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Why Your Code Doesn't Work

In general, [Kernel#gets](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns a String with a trailing newline. Therefore, [Array#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete) has no matching elements.

### A Working Alternative

You need to convert your input to an Integer for the #gets method. It's also useful to return a value from your method. The following works, and also serves to validate the user's input:

```
require 'pp'

def delete_from_array array
  print 'Number to be deleted: '
  array.delete Integer(gets)
  pp array
end

array = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
delete_from_array array.dup
```

Note that #delete will modify the original array, rather than returning a copy. In most cases, you will probably want to use #dup to ensure that you aren't modifying your original array. On the other hand, if you *want* the side-effects, then just elide the call to #dup when passing the array as an argument.